# Grunt with Jasmine/Mocha: accessing tests on filesystem or through webserver?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, jasmine, mocha.js

I am setting up a testing environment for a client-side javascript project.

I am using Grunt for my build automation. As a test framework I am going to use Jasmine or Mocha.

I notice that both [grunt-contrib-jasmine](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jasmine) and [grunt-mocha](https://github.com/kmiyashiro/grunt-mocha) can be configured to run the test from the local filesystem or through a webserver (typically using grunt-contrib-connect). i.e by using options.urls (Mocha) or options.host (Jasmine).

The default Yeoman generator "webapp" uses the latter method.

I would imagine that running from the filesystem is more performant and less error prone. What is the advantage of going through a webserver? Or what scenarios require going through a webserver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your tests are accessed through a webserver you gain the ability to run them on browsers on other devices. Depending on how your test suite looks you could use [time-grunt](https://www.npmjs.org/package/time-grunt) to determine how long runs take via direct access and through the web. Then either choose web if there isn't a performance hit, or consider having two paths, disk for speed, and web for testing with other devices.